# how to convert a certificate file to const char certBuffer[CERTIFICATE_SIZE] in openssl?

Tags: c, openssl, android-source

I 'm working on **aosp** and met a **problem about adding my certificate with public key** in the

```
bootable/bootloader/lk/platform/msm_shared/certificate.c file.
```

Actually, I don't know **how to generate** 
    certBuffer[CERTIFICATE_SIZE] array.

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

After I generate one file cer.pem certificate from cer.key (device/qcom/common) I have run this command on terminal to generate a hexadecimal string:

```
xxd -i cer.pem | sed -e 's/unsigned char .* = {/const unsigned char OEM_KEYSTORE[] = {/g' -e 's/unsigned int .* = .*;//g'
```

Even though, this command generated a hexadecimal string, but I still doubt this result.